# What does "CONST func(arg);" mean in C language?

Tags: c, semantics

[This](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/parse1.c) is a c program demonstrating some basic usage of the libxml2 library.  Below is quoted from the main function:

```
LIBXML_TEST_VERSION example1Func(argv[1]);
```

What does this statement stand for?

I can only tell that LIBXML_TEST_VERSION is obviously a constant, and after that is a function call, that function returns nothing (void). But I've no idea what it means the statement in whole.

Comment: I feel terribly sorry now because the line from the original program I've linked to is actually two lines. I guess it's my IDE's auto indent system made the wrong decision. So this question is actually meaningless.

Comment: Still, you guys are impressively fast!

Comment: No problem - today we all learned that: all uppercase symbols are not necessarily constants, that you should not trust the formatting of code, and what the LIBXML_TEST_VERSION macro does. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIBXML_TEST_VERSION` is not a constant - it's a macro - see the documentation here:

```
Macro: LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

#define LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
Macro to check that the libxml version in use is compatible with the version the software has been compiled against
```

It's also nothing to do with the call to `example1func()` - the code should look like this (comments are mine):

```
LIBXML_TEST_VERSION    // test libxml version

example1func();        // call example1func
```

Comment: +1: This kind of macro is irritating, though, for exactly this sort of confusion.  I would prefer it if the macro didn't define the trailing `;`, which would at least force you to explicitly suffix the instantation with a `;`, thus reducing visual confusion.

Comment: @Oli: indeed - typically multi-line macros should be wrapped in `do { ... } while (0)` to allow for a terminating semicolon

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though `LIBXML_TEST_VERSION` is a macro that expands to one or more statements. From [Google code search](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22%23define+LIBXML_TEST_VERSION%22&sbtn=Search), it appears the definition is something like:

```
#define LIBXML_TEST_VERSION xmlCheckVersion(20703);
```

where `20703` is whatever version you're compiling against.

This statement is independent from the call to `example1Func()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the standard convention to name C preprocessor macros in ALL_UPPERCASE. As you suggest, this is often used for compile-time constants. However, there are other uses.

Now to your example. The original source looks like this (comments are mine):

```
LIBXML_TEST_VERSION    /* line 1 */
example1Func(argv[1]); /* line 2 */
```

The first line is a C macro. The second line is a function call. The two are not part of the same statement as your question implies. It is unfortunate that the way `LIBXML_TEST_VERSION` is defined it does not require a semicolon at the end; if this were the case, there would be no confusion around whether the two lines are part of the same statement.

In case you're wondering what exactly is [`LIBXML_TEST_VERSION`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlversion.html#LIBXML_TEST_VERSION):

```
Macro: LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

#define LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
Macro to check that the libxml version in use is compatible
with the version the software has been compiled against
```